# Full House v. Quads

Tags: poker-theory, odds, poker-strategy

What are the odds of getting quadded when you have the highest full house on the table? I would reckon it's very rare, but I have done it once to an opponent.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen it on TV a few times

Based on hand [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) it is 0.000256 (quad) * 0.0017 (boat) = 0.00000044

From the boat there are 45 cards out and need to match the pair on the board
So the odds of getting *quadded* are:
[(2/2) / (45/2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) = 0.00101 = 0.1%
Which also = 2/45 * 1/44

Highest or lower boat is immaterial.  Quads beat a full house.

Comment: What about a board like AKKKx and you hold an ace? The risk of someone holding a K is much higher than that.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin OK, what about a board like AKKKx?  You are welcome to run those numbers.  I just don't think OP would have asked the question in that manner if the board  tripped.  A lone ace would not be the highest full house on that table.

Answer (score -3):

There’s zero chance of quads if u have “the better” full house. Meaning queens full of 3s. Vs 3s full of queens. The boat 3s full of queens can b beat by quads

Comment: Just a comment here to highlight this is incorrect. A player could have something like pocket kings, vs pocket 3s with a board of K33XX. To say there is a zero chance of quads against a full house is totally incorrect.